# why doesn't my JS function fire on the onresize event?

Tags: javascript, html, centering, event-listener, onresize

```js
function getCentralPosition() {

  // This script verticaly centers the heading you see on the main home page video //


  // First save the parent div that houses the heading element into a variable named parentDiv.
  var parentDiv = document.getElementById('home-section-1');

  // Now obtain the total height (including padding, borders etc) of this parentDiv
  var parentDivHeight = parentDiv.offsetHeight;

  // Save the child div element that houses the heading into a variable named childDiv
  var childDiv = document.getElementById('home-first-overlay');

  // Now obtain the total height (including padding, borders etc) of this childDiv
  var childDivHeight = childDiv.offsetHeight;

  // Calculate the height difference between the parentDiv and childDiv by subtracting their heights and storing them 
  // in a variable named heightDiff

  var heightDiff = parentDivHeight - childDivHeight;

  // Obtain the precise position required from the top of the parentDiv by dividing heightDiff by 2

  var pos_from_top = heightDiff / 2;

  // assign pos_from_top as the value for 'top' on childDiv using "px"

  childDiv.style.top = pos_from_top + "px";

}

window.addEventListener("onresize", getCentralPosition);
```

without the window resize eventlistener, I used the code as is - but the idea is that it also stays in the center when one trys to resize the browser window etc.  Thought not necessary, i just wanted to achieve this. Any ideas as to what I should be trying ?

Comment: You probably want `window.addEventListener("resize", getCentralPosition);` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resize_event#addEventListener_equivalent

Comment: ah yes,  one works as ie fallback and without appending 'on'resize ( just resize ) is the main way heh.

i remember this from John Ducketts book :-)

Comment: Yep that seems to have worked skovy, thanks!

Also, I added the line ' document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",getCentralPosition); '

because it only centered when i began resizing,  not on load :-D

anyway I can combine those two eventlisteners as one , so they can listen on both events same time ?  I can't remember if i did this before, it rings a bell...

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for the [`"resize"` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resize_event#addEventListener_equivalent)

Here is the updated snippet (it errors without the proper HTML, but shows the event firing).

```js
function getCentralPosition() {

  // This script verticaly centers the heading you see on the main home page video //


  // First save the parent div that houses the heading element into a variable named parentDiv.
  var parentDiv = document.getElementById('home-section-1');

  // Now obtain the total height (including padding, borders etc) of this parentDiv
  var parentDivHeight = parentDiv.offsetHeight;

  // Save the child div element that houses the heading into a variable named childDiv
  var childDiv = document.getElementById('home-first-overlay');

  // Now obtain the total height (including padding, borders etc) of this childDiv
  var childDivHeight = childDiv.offsetHeight;

  // Calculate the height difference between the parentDiv and childDiv by subtracting their heights and storing them 
  // in a variable named heightDiff

  var heightDiff = parentDivHeight - childDivHeight;

  // Obtain the precise position required from the top of the parentDiv by dividing heightDiff by 2

  var pos_from_top = heightDiff / 2;

  // assign pos_from_top as the value for 'top' on childDiv using "px"

  childDiv.style.top = pos_from_top + "px";

}

window.addEventListener("resize", getCentralPosition);
```

Answer (score 0):

I use a similar function to adjust a dynamic svg graph based screen size.
I just place the onresize="function()" code in the  tag and it works out of the box.